# What's the benefit of Docker Compose Switch over a symlink?

Tags: compatibility, docker-compose

There are at least two ways to use Docker Compose v2 as a drop-in replacement for Docker Compose v1:

- [Compose Switch](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#compose-switch)
- `# ln -s /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

From the current [README](https://github.com/docker/compose#where-to-get-docker-compose) (2.1.0 / 2021-11-09):

> V2 is not a standalone binary anymore, and installation scripts will have to be adjusted. Some commands are different.

This sounds like v2 cannot be used as a drop-in replacement for v1.

From the [release notes of 2.0.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.0.1):

> Added support for running the plugin as a standalone program. Like `docker-compose` v1 would behave

So what's the effective difference between these two ways?